# How to write to JSON with SwiftyJSON in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I was able to successfully read a local JSON file using SwiftyJSON. Now I would like to write an array of dictionaries for a to-do list, with each array element including a title, and a timestamp. Here is what my JSON looks like:

```
[
 {
 "Content": "Walk the dog",
 "Created": "October 24, 2015",
 },
 {
 "Content": "Hello",
 "Created": "October 25, 2015",
 }
]
```

I have a function (which does not work) that is supposed to change the JSON data when I press a button on my storyboard. That looks like:

```
@IBAction func setJSON(_ sender: Any) {
    let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Data", ofType: "json")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: file!), options: NSData.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped)
    if let data = data {
        var json = JSON(data: data)
        json.dictionaryObject = ["name":"Alex", "age":25]
        loadJSON()
    }
}
```

Note that it does not return any error, it just doesn't show any difference in the JSON.

Thank you!

**Update:**

I tried logging the JSON data to the console, and it appears that the JSON data is being changed, my problem is just saving that data to the local JSON file.

Comment: Try logging it to the console? Looks to me like it's working, you're just not updating the UI.

Comment: @brandonscript Thanks for the quick response! I just tried that, and the JSON variable is being changed. I think my problem is that the JSON isn't being saved to the JSON file.

Comment: did you save it to the json file? NO! you fave to do it by yourself

Comment: @muescha and how would I do that? That's exactly my question...

Comment: no  thats not you just ask "to json" not to json file

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#string-representation

Comment: and the string you can save in a file